# Missing file crti.o when compiling GCC-9.2.0

Tags: gcc, lfs

On Fedora 30 --> compiling GCC-9.2.0.
I find solutions to similar problems, but not exactly the same. Some say its a bug.
First errors come when preparing for compilation with

```
../configure --target=$LFS_TGT / --prefix=/tools / ...etc.
The errors here are:
/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 inside /
```

Obviously it is searching for the 32-bit in `/lib`. I work on 64-bit. But I ignore these errors and do the next command make , where i get similar, not the same error message and stop there, can't finish the compilation. Errors are:

```
functions are only in"; echo "   the static library.  */"; echo "GROUP
( libgcc_s.so.1 -lgcc )" ) > ./libgcc_s.so
/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]:*** [Makefile:992: libgcc_s.so] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory /mnt/lfs/build/gcc-9.2.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc
make[2]:*** [Makefile:21399: all-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory /mnt/lfs/build/gcc-9.2.0/build
make[1]: ***[Makefile:26727: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory /mnt/lfs/build/gcc-9.2.0/build
make: *** [Makefile:1000: all] Error 2
root:/mnt/lfs/build/gcc-9.2.0/build#
```

I run the command find `/usr/ -name crt*` and I find the missing file here:
`/usr/lib64/crti.o`

But obviously the system does not find it. Its in the 64-bit directory. Should I install the lib 32-bit? Or this would be needed in the first error message, but not for the second part when i run make?
How to solve this?